# XAML Data Binding ignoring spell-checker

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, data-binding

I've got a simple two-way binding in my XAML (Xamarin Forms on an iPad, if it matters):

```
<Entry x:Name="ProgramName" Text="{Binding ProgramName, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

In my data model object I've got the associated 'ProgramName' property, and some debugging so I can see what's happening:

```
string m_programName;
public string ProgramName
{
    get { return m_programName; }
    set
    {
        Debug.WriteLine ("ProgramDataModel.ProgramName.set(\"" + value + "\")");
        if (value != m_programName)
        {
            m_programName = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke (this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs ("ProgramName"));
        }
    }
}
```

That works as expected, unless the iPad decides to spell-correct my typing.

If I enter "Emptygg" and then close the keyboard entry pane, the screen shows that my text entry field now contains "Emptying" but the console debug shows:

```
ProgramDataModel.ProgramName.set("")
ProgramDataModel.ProgramName.set("E")
ProgramDataModel.ProgramName.set("Em") 
ProgramDataModel.ProgramName.set("Emp") 
ProgramDataModel.ProgramName.set("Empt")
ProgramDataModel.ProgramName.set("Empty")
ProgramDataModel.ProgramName.set("Emptyg")
ProgramDataModel.ProgramName.set("Emptygg")
```

I never get notified about the final spell-correct change to my Entry field.